# Spring JPA. How to get only a list of IDs using @Query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write this to fetch List and i have to pass the list of Ids as parameter :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT OutbreakDiagnosticTests FROM OutbreakDiagnosticTests WHERE OutbreakDiagnosticTests.outbreaks  in (:outbreakIds) ")
List<OutbreakDiagnosticTests> getDiagnosticTestsByOutbreaks(@Param("outbreakIds") List<Long> outbreakIds);
```

My Entity is this that i am using to query is this :

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(OutbreakDiagnosticTestManagerImpl.class)
@Table(name = "outbreak_diagnostic_tests")
public class OutbreakDiagnosticTests extends AbstractTemporalWorkingData implements Serializable{
  
/**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 636298998880960358L;

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, name = "obdt_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long obdtId;

  @Column(nullable = false, name = "nature", length = 255)
  private String nature;

  @Column(nullable = true, name = "diagnostic_test_req", length = 255)
  private String diagnosticTestReq;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "outbreakDiagnosticTests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @Filter(name = "workingData")
  private Set<TestsResults> testsResults;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "outbreak_id", nullable = false)
  private Outbreaks outbreaks;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "diag_test_id", nullable = true)
  private DiagnosticTests diagTests;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "lab_id", nullable = true)
  private Laboratories lab;

  @Column(nullable = false, name = "is_field")
  private Boolean isField = false;
```

But i am getting this exception after running :

```
Error creating bean with name 'labTestSummariesDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'obDiagTestRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'outbreakDiagnosticTestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.wahisplus.wcommon.repository.outbreak.OutbreakDiagnosticTestRepository.getDiagnosticTestsByOutbreaks(java.util.List)!
```

Can some one help me to fetch the List using the above method or can tell me what i am doing wrong in this.I dnt want to do using native i.e (nativeQuery = true) using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alias like `OutbreakDiagnosticTests o` and for select id, use `o.outbreaks.id` and make sure you autowired properly repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM OutbreakDiagnosticTests o WHERE o.outbreaks.id IN (:outbreakIds) ")
List<OutbreakDiagnosticTests> getDiagnosticTestsByOutbreaks(@Param("outbreakIds") List<Long> outbreakIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using Spring Data JPA, a method is provided OOTB:
List findAllById(Iterable ids);

This method takes in a List of non-null ids and returns you back the records against those Ids. Since you are not using DTO Concept and fetching al columns for a bundh of ids, why not use this method to work with.